# Cannot resolve the collation conflict between “SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS” and “Latin1_General_CI_AS” in the equal to operation

Tags: sql-server

I am getting this error when I am running an `ALTER PROCEDURE` statement in a SQL Server database. The procedure has a `SELECT` statement with `OUTER JOIN` between two tables in two different databases.

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between “SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS” and “Latin1_General_CI_AS” in the equal to operation

I realize that there are multiple similar questions where collation is actually different between the two tables or even the fields that are part of the `JOIN`. However, this situation is different:

- All tables and all text fields in both databases have the same collation - `Latin1_General_CI_AS`.
- Both databases have the same default collation - `Latin1_General_CI_AS`.

What could be a possible reason for this error in this scenario, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: You can cast/convert the collation in the join by applying the matching collation name on the other column (which one you pick is up to you and the data subset). Just add `COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS` (or whatever your collation is you want to use) *after* the name of the column.

Comment: Databases and tables don't have collation. Only string columns have a collation. The database default collation is only applicable to the creation of new columns when the collation is not specified. So examining the database default is not particularly useful in solving a problem like this unless the process involves creating new columns in some fashion. The short answer is you need to find the statement that produces the error and figure out why different collations are in use.

Comment: In addition to the above temp tables use `tempdb` which can have a different collation. However the solution is simple as already stated by Igor.

Comment: @Igor, I realize that adding COLLATE Latin_General_CI_AS or COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT will resolve the error, and this is usually a solution when the two columns in question have different collations. However, in this case all columns have the same collation. So I am curious why adding the COLLATE statement is necessary in this situation, and where SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS in the error message could possibly come from.